# multiple api keys for 1 site

Tags: api, key, geocoding, here-api

I'm creating a medical transportation website that manages the day to day tasks of medical transportation companies.  Can each company that signs up under my website create and use their own api keys so that they get billed individually by here developer?  I'd like to offer the website for free for each company to sign up with me and their only bill to be from here developer.

Thanks

Comment: I believe when a call is made, the API key that comes with the call will be charged for billing purposes. So if you can have the companies signing up provide an API key that you pass on the calls it should be doable.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response.